# Triggering click event on first element of a list using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to trigger click on first li of a List.I am using ng-repeat to populate the List.I know it can be done using a directive but not sure how to do it.

HTML:

```
<ul  id="my-ul" click-first-row>
      <li ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-click="getRow(row,$index)" >{{row.requestId}}</li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App',[]).controller('Ctr',function($scope){
      $scope.rows = res.inboxNewRecords;
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#my-ul li')).triggerHandler('click');
      $scope.getRow = function(data,index){
        $scope.newReq = data;
      };
    }).directive('clickFirstRow',function(){
      return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,el,attr){
          console.log(el[0]);
          el[0].find('li').triggerHandler('click')
        }
      };
    });
```

Please find the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qjj9EEuhXrZwSLuuSaRT?p=preview) for the same.

Comment: when do u want to trigger it?

Comment: After the list is populated.I mean by default click should be triggered for first "li".

Comment: Where does `res.inboxNewRecords` comes from ?

Comment: Its there in plunker.Please find it.I have not included here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things with your code:

1. "el[0]" will return a native element that won't support the .find() selector. You want to find the first `<li>` and wrap it with angular.element so you can call triggerHandler() on it.
2. This code will fire too early, the click handler won't be properly bound before you trigger the click. You could wrap it in a `$timeout()`, or better still use the `$$postDigest` callback.

Working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/O6BeOEieSdNj3Y3KkAYc?p=preview

```
scope.$$postDigest(function() {
    var firstRow = el.find('li')[0];
    angular.element(firstRow).triggerHandler('click');
});
```

However, for the purposes you describe, a better approach would be to bind your `newReq` scope variable to the first row immediately after you get the response:

```
$scope.rows = res.inboxNewRecords;
if ($scope.rows && $scope.rows.length > 0) {
    $scope.newReq = $scope.rows[0];
}
```

There are a number of reasons why this is better for setting initial values:

- By binding to the click event in this way you might get undesirable results if other listeners are bound to the same click event
- You may fail to receive a default value if the click event fails to trigger (i.e. the row is later made read-only)
- The pattern of updating state after a digest cycle can lead to unpredictable behaviour, as it gives an opportunity for other actions to occur earlier in the lifecycle, i.e. before the initial scope value has been set

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. I had some trouble with the StackOverflow formatting but it seems to be showing the code block properly now.

Comment: using $timeout or $$postDigest is really bad practice.

Comment: @Maxime the whole "click triggering" thing is a bad practice.

Comment: I agree the approach could use a review, but the question asks how to trigger the click event on an element. This answer explains how that is done. I take your point though and will update it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for a "default" selected option.

If so, here's the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/szj72Vtzw431EZY52wEL?p=preview

Basically, you have to set a default value to the `$scope.newReq` variable in the controller:

```
$scope.newReq = $scope.rows[0];
```

Do it, instead of "hacking" the click event. That's not the correct way to address this issue.

Comment: @UmakantaBehera triggering a fake click event is not the proper way to set up a default option. Set the `$scope.newReq` to the first element of `$scope.rows` array instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't access DOM from controller.

Then, I think you might want to "trigger getRow function for the first row" instead of "trigger **click** on first row". This is really different.

If this is what you're trying to achieve, it could be done like that :

```
angular
.module('App',[])
.controller('Ctr', function($scope, $http) {
    // launch http request from controller even tho
    // it'd probably be a better idea to handle it from a service
    $http
        .get('http://your-backend-url-to-get-inbox')
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.rows = res.data.inboxNewRecords;

            if (typeof $scope.rows[0] !== 'undefined') {
                $scope.getRow($scope.rows[0], 0);
            }
        });

    $scope.getRow = function(row, index){
        $scope.newReq = data;
    };
});
```